# How to change action in custom form created by contact form 7 plugin in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

> I created a custom form using contact form 7 plugin in wordpress. I just want to set the action of custom form.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with javascript/jquery:

```
$('#myform').attr('action', 'http://example.com/myaction.php');
```

Comment: I think wordpress protects against this